# How to redirect different page from same controller function in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to redirect 2 different page from this controller function along with value.Here is my code. It works but both of time url become same.what shuld I do?

```
//in routes.php
Route::post('/','mycontroller@check');

// in controller.php 
public function check(Request $request)
{
    $c_email = $request->email;
    $c_pass=$request->pass;
    $c_type=$request->select;

   $var=DB::select("SELECT * FROM reg where email = '$c_email' and Password = '$c_pass' and type = '$c_type'");
   if ($var) {
      return view('farmer')->with('user',$var);
   // return redirect('farmer')->with('user',$var);
   }
   else {
    $msg="Invalid login";
    return view('index')->with('show',$msg);

   }
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you just `redirect()` to another url/route?

Comment: I did that but how I can pass that variable named $var.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry You want your view `'farmer'` to have the variable `$var` passed down from the controler?

Comment: Yes. i am trying still now. but it's not working

Comment: `return view('farmer', compact('var'));` This should do the trick. I would suggest renaming the **var** to something more readable like **user**

Comment: In routes.php file there is Route::post('/','mycontroller@check');
should I need to add anything else?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually redirect u can use the redirect() helper as statet in the official docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/redirects

You can also pass data

```
redirect('/my-route')->with(['user' => $var]);
```

The passed data can then be accesses through the session helper

```
$var = session('user')
```

HOWEVER, it seems like you have major issues in your code. Your password does not seem to be encrypted. Also there's no reason to use plain sql instead of eloquent here.

The route that is shown in the browser is defined in your

```
Route::post('/','mycontroller@check');
```

If you just return different views, the route does not change. You need to redirect to other views.

If you redirect to other routes you will ofcourse need to add / define them.

```
Route::get('/my-route', function() {}); // or post etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion . I did according to your answer but still url is same. I also added in routes.php
Route::get('farmer', function() {});

Comment: you will ofcourse need to add content to the function or underly a controller method - and you need to redirect to the route in your check function